# How to open Chrome with vscode liveserver on Ubuntu without grouping them

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and the latest versions for VSCode, Google Chrome and Liveserver for them.

Whenever I open a document on a new window with liveserver it opens a chrome window but grouped with the favourite icon of VSCode. I have a fav icon of Chrome as well on the Ubuntu favbar, but it ignores it.

I've tried chaning the custom browser on setting.json of liveserver, but it didn't work. There's another similar question here but with firefox, and what he did didn't work here either.

So what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

This will only partially solve your problem, but: If your main problem is, that `Alt+Tab` won't work as easily, because you can not quickly switch between vscode and chrome - you can fix that issue by changing your keyboard shortcuts: You need to set `Alt+Tab` to `Switch Windows` instead of `Switch Applications` (To get to the keyboard shortcuts, press windows key and type keyboard).

This works for everything that vscode opens, which will always be grouped under vscode, presumably because it is its child process.

Comment: Keyboard shortcut on windows, ubuntu vm or vscode?

Comment: in ubuntu. If it is a vm, then in that

Comment: Well, that was a nice try but VirtualBox will aways switch windows aplications even if I select to not capture these commands. I suppose it's the price I have to pay for being forced to use a Linux VM for my bootcamp that also requires Microsoft Teams for it lol. Thanks anyway